# Excel - Return column header for top n values across columns array with row criteria

Tags: excel

I'm currently trying identify the columns which contain the top n values for given conditions (using row match).
I have been able to use AGGREGATE to identify specific row matches but am not sure how to apply this across columns, with the added complexity of identifying the top values.

The goal is given a specific criteria - e.g. code 5010110000, with criteria 5, 1, 1, the formula should look up columns p1 and p7 for the particular row and return the column name with the top 3 values. In this case the result should then be p5, p7, p3, etc, in e.g. cell a1, a2, a3, ... respectively.

From current examples it seems like vba would be the clear answer. Would it be possible to use index/match/aggregate? Any advice will be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

[image: Updated Dummy Table]

Comment: Did you try the use of LARGE function?

Comment: Doesn't p1 always contain the largest value (>1,000)?

Comment: @DavidGarcíaBodego I'm not sure on how to use large on top of the row lookup function unfortunately. I have updated the image to include the fields for the criteria and the output cells. Hopefully that will make the issue clearer.

Comment: @TomSharpe In the event the criteria is 6010110000, the row to look within would the 9th row and in that case p5 would have the largest value.

Comment: With the actual data, on the first line, you are looking for the 3 biggest values. `LARGE(array,position)` it is taking whatever range, column or row and it is teruning you the values in order so, if you are bringing `LARGE($A4:$A10,1)`, you will get the biggest value in this range, for the second one you should use `LARGE($A4:$A10,2)`. I am not understanding the influence of the code and criteria.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion caused. The goal is to identify which column header (e2:k2), contains the largest values. The comparison is across columns, so if given the criteria 6010110000, 6, 1, 1, the formula should look across e11:k11, identifying the top n values. 

In this case the top value is 1,308.21 in p5, so the first cell output in m4 should be p5, output in m5 should be p7 and so on. Does this make it clearer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one:

On Cell A1 use: `=LARGE($A4:$A10,1)`
On Cell A2 use: `=LARGE($A4:$A10,2)`
On Cell A3 use: `=LARGE($A4:$A10,3)`

And drag that ones down. I am assuming that the first row is "A", if it is not, just change the target.

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks! Created a workaround after being inspired by this. 
The workaround involves creating an array of p1:p7 value and labels, which is refreshed when the criteria is updated. The large function is then used on the fixed array to identify the top values.